# nodejs - net or http module

Tags: node.js, http, chat

I'm doing chat system with `nodejs`. To create a node server I can either use `net` or `http` module. So what is the difference and benefit of using each of them ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`http` is built on top of `net` (which handles the TCP layer underlying HTTP).

I imagine that your "chat system" will have browser-based clients, since node.js isn't great for GUIs/desktop apps at the moment. If that's the case, you'll most likely want to use `http`.

A node.js chat server has already been made - [node-chat](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-chat). You could build yours on top of this, or take a look at its source code for some ideas.

Comment: the node-chat example is not so good. It uses long-polling technique instead websocket. And when using long polling, sooner or later the browser will crash due overhad of http request. I was taking the websocket approach, and ultilizing flash socket as fallback for unspported browser.