# How to check if port is in use (remote machine)

Tags: windows, port, telnet, netstat

Is there any possibility to check if specific port on remote Windows machine (for example 3389 for RDP) is already in use? Localy I could use netstat, but I want to check this remotely. Can I do this with Telnet? Or something?

EDIT: I tried PortQry (proposed by user3365848: http://www.gfi.com/blog/scan-open-ports-in-windows-a-quick-guide/), but this give me only information if system is LISTENING on 3389 port, but not if someone have active RDP session. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: http://www.gfi.com/blog/scan-open-ports-in-windows-a-quick-guide/ Kindly check the link, it describes about local and remote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check whether an open port is TCP or HTTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24964500/how-do-i-check-whether-an-open-port-is-tcp-or-http)