# NodeJS How to implement request/response in net module

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http

I am new to NodeJS and working on a project in which I am using 'net' module. My question is can we implement request, response model using **'net'** module as we can achieve in **HTTP** module i.e. I want that when user type localhost:port number in browser I can send response to the browser. I can achieve the same using HTTP and unable to understand the basic difference between **'Net'** and **'HTTP'** module:

**My 'Net' Module code is :**

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function (con)
{   
    con.on('data', function (data)
    {
        <some code>
    });

    con.on('end', function ()
    {
        console.log('nodeServer disconnected');
    });
});
server.listen(8888, function ()
{ 
  console.log('nodeServer listening port:8888');
});
```

**Following is the 'HTTP' module code:**

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*" });
    var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('test', 'utf8'));
    res.write(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
    res.end();  
}).listen(8888);
```

The reason I want to implement to implement this in **Net** module is that I am getting some XML from a url after fixed interval which I need to convert to JSON and return the JSON to user when requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this post
[nodejs - net or http module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739028/nodejs-net-or-http-module)

It states that http is built on top of net

I can't see this on the NodeJS doc pages though

http://nodejs.org/api/net.html

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: Thanks for reply @Neil but I have already gone through the aforementioned post and going through NodeJS API but as I have mentioned I am new to this so its a little bit tough for me to get a better understanding of these two.

Comment: I don't think you need net. I would just try and use http.request to get your xml and then http.createServer to serve it to the browser

Comment: I was also thinking about the same approach but I don't know why the project requirement is so complicated. The thing is, there is a Java scheduler which ask for XML from a URL and return that XML to my NodeJS module and I convert that XML to JSON and return it to Client. If there is anyway to implement my Net module into HTTP module then that will also be alright. The main concern is I want whenever Java scheduler(Which return XML after every 1 minutes) return XML data then I can receive the same in my NodeJS module

Comment: So are you thinking of using net because you have to get the XML from this java scheduler? Can you not just go directly to the URL yourself and use http.request?

Comment: Indeed **http** is based on **net** as you can see here:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js#L4

Answer (score 0):

Basically you use the **net** module when you need to do lower level things than what **http** module let you do.

**http**: wraps everything in the *request* and *response* objects for you to interact with.

**net**: gives you the TCP socket itself for you to do whatever you want.

@neil-shah indeed **http** is based on **net** as you can see here:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js#L4